# data.table update join by group

Tags: r, join, data.table

I have a specific `data.table` question: is there a way to do an update join but by group ? Let me give an example:

```
df1 <- data.table(ID = rep(letters[1:3],each = 3),x = c(runif(3,0,1),runif(3,1,2),runif(3,2,3)))
df2 <- data.table(ID = c(letters[1],letters[1:5]))

> df2
   ID
1:  a
2:  a
3:  b
4:  c
5:  d
6:  e

> df1
   ID         x
1:  a 0.9719153
2:  a 0.8897171
3:  a 0.7067390
4:  b 1.2122764
5:  b 1.7441528
6:  b 1.3389710
7:  c 2.8898255
8:  c 2.0388562
9:  c 2.3025064
```

I would like to do something like

```
df2[df1,plouf := sample(i.x),on ="ID"]
```

But for each `ID` group, meaning that `plouf` would be a sample of the `x` values for each corresponding `ID`. The above line of code does not work this way, it sample the whole `x` vector:

```
> df2

   ID     plouf
1:  a 1.3099715
2:  a 0.8540039
3:  b 2.0767138
4:  c 0.6530148
5:  d        NA
6:  e        NA
```

You see that the values of `plouf` are not the `x` corresponding to the `ID` group of `df1`. I would like that the `plouf` value is between 0 and 1 for `a`, 1 and 2 for `b`, and 2 and 3 for `c`. I want to sample without replacement.
I tried :

```
df2[df1,plouf := as.numeric(sample(i.x,.N)),on ="ID",by = .EACHI]
```

which does not work:

```
Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
  cannot take a sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE'
```

This other attempt seems to be working:

```
df2$plouf <- df2[df1,on ="ID"][,sample(x,df2[ID == ID2,.N]),by = .(ID2 = ID)]$V1
```

But I find it hard to read or understand, it could be problematic for more than one grouping variable, and I am not sure it is quite efficient. I am sure there is a nice simple way to write it, but I don't have it. Any idea ?

Comment: Another fun option: `df2[, plouf := sample(df1[.(.BY[[1L]]), x, on = .(ID)], .N), by = ID]`

Comment: what does the `[[1L]]` bit mean?

Comment: @DavidArenburg Wow, not sure to understand it properly. If you have a bit of time, I would use a more detailed explanation. But thanks for the answer

Comment: It's pretty much your working idea but in a proper data.table syntax. For each `ID` in `df2` I'm sampling from df1 for the same `ID` according to the amount of rows for that `ID` in `dt2`. I believe this is pretty much you were trying to do. In either way, this was just for fun in order to improve your attempt. chinsoons solution should be the faster and more idiomic way, I would think. The `.BY[[1L]]` part, if you wandering, are just the `ID` value in the certain group. e.g., for the first group in would be `c(a, a)`, for the second group `b`, etc. I'm using it in order to join back to `df1`.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thank you for the explanation. I did not know the .BY[[1L]], it can help a lot. The fun is important, and I learnt something useful, so perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option:

```
df1[df2[, .N, ID], on=.(ID), sample(x, N), by=.EACHI]
```

output:

```
   ID        V1
1:  a 0.2655087
2:  a 0.3721239
3:  b 1.2016819
4:  c 2.6607978
5:  d        NA
6:  e        NA
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(0L)
df1 <- data.table(ID = rep(letters[1:3],each = 3),x = c(runif(3,0,1),runif(3,1,2),runif(3,2,3)))
df2 <- data.table(ID = c(letters[1],letters[1:5]))
```

---

Addressing comment:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(0L)
df1 <- data.table(ID = rep(letters[1:3],each = 3),
    NAME = rep(LETTERS[1:3],each = 3),
    x = c(runif(3,0,1),runif(3,1,2),runif(3,2,3)))
df2 <- data.table(ID = c(letters[1],letters[1:5]),
    NAME = c(LETTERS[1],LETTERS[1:5]))

df2[, ri := rowid(ID, NAME)][
    df1[df2[, .N, .(ID, NAME)], on=.(ID, NAME), .(ri=1L:N, VAL=sample(x, N)), by=.EACHI],
    on=.(ri, ID, NAME), VAL := VAL]
df2
```

If it is too repetitive to type `ID, NAME`, you can use

```
cols <- c("ID", "NAME")
df2[, ri := rowidv(.SD, cols)][
    df1[df2[, .N, cols], on=cols, .(ri=1L:N, VAL=sample(x, N)), by=.EACHI],
    on=c("ri", cols), VAL := VAL]
df2
```

Comment: would this solution work for multiple grouping variable ?

Comment: I actually have a problem with this solution: I wanted to have V1 directly assigned to a variable in df2, like during an update join. Here I would need somehow to assign/merge the output back to df2

Comment: Just so that I don’t misunderstand you, can you kindly share an example?

Answer (score 1):

**Sample with replacement**

You can do that like this:

```
df2[, plouf := df1[df2, on = .(ID),
                        sample(x, size = 1),
                        by=.EACHI]$V1]
```

You can join on the `ID` variable, but you must specify `by=.EACHI` as you are returning multiple values. The `$V1` tells it to return the first column of the results.

Result:

```
   ID      sample
1:  a 0.042188292
2:  a 0.002502247
3:  b 1.145714600
4:  c 2.541768627
5:  d          NA
6:  e          NA
```

**Sample without replacement**

Its not pretty but it works:

```
df2$plouf = as.numeric(NA)

# create temporary table of number of sample required for each group
temp = df2[, .N, by = ID]

for(i in temp$ID){
  # create a temporary sample
  temp_sample = sample(df1[i==ID]$x, size = temp[ID==i]$n, replace = FALSE)

  # assign sample
  for(j in seq(1, length(temp_sample))){
    df2[ID==i][j]$plouf = temp_sample[j] 
  }
}
```

Thanks to @David Arenburg for help

Comment: yes but no, I want to use `.N` because the size of the group may vary. I will edit my question

Comment: you can only return 1 sampled value from each group. Do you want to sample from the first `N` rows of each group?

Comment: you can refer to the size of `N` by `dim(df2[ID==i.ID])`, for example: `df2[, sample := df1[df2, on = .(ID), sample(x, size = dim(df2[ID==i.ID])), by=.EACHI]$V1]`, but you cannot return more than 1 value per group

Comment: I want to sample all the rows of the group. I want to sample the 3 rows of group `a` of `df1` to extract 2 value and assign it to the group `a` of `df2`

Comment: exact. I want without replacement. Your solution is with replacement

Comment: ok, I added an answer. It will not be super fast but it should work